# How do I use co-authors plus with Timber?

Tags: wordpress, timber

Installed Co-Authors Plus. Created a guest user. Set a post with this guest user. Does not override. In Twig:

```
<p class="article-byline__author">By <a href="{{post.author.path}}">{{post.author.name}}</a></p>
```

What is the correct method? Using Timber as a plugin Version 1.1.5, latest WP and Co-Authors Plus.

Answer (score 0):

@user2340584 @j0861: as of [Timber 1.1.10 we've added a ton of features](https://wordpress.org/plugins/timber-library/changelog/) to make Co-Authors Plus work out-of-the box with guest authors, etc. Run an upgrade and your code will work!